# $(\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z)[X] \not\cong \Bbb Z[X]\oplus \Bbb Z[X]\,$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Well i tried to prove it but failed. They are both commutative and have the same set of units. So i can't see a property of one ring which the other ring does not possess. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rings $(\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z)[X]$ and $\Bbb Z[X]\oplus \Bbb Z[X]$ are isomorphic via
$$ \sum_{k}^n(a_k,b_k)X^k\mapsto (\sum_{k}^na_kX^k,\sum_{k}^nb_kX^k)$$

Comment: Oh so the book was wrong...... It said that the two rings are nonisomorphic. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Mathcho, could you please be so kind and tell us what book is this? Maybe there is some subtlety that we miss.

Comment: @Mathcho, one more thing: even when given by a high-reputation user, answers should be verified. Did you really check Hagen's answer?

Comment: It is a problem 5.4.12 from the stephen lovett's algebra. And i have checked that the function above is an isomorphism. I hope i am not wrong.

Comment: Which element maps to (x,1)?